# Can I install a new version of Ubuntu over old Ubuntu that I forgot the password to

Tags: dual-boot

I have forgotten my password for an older version of Ubuntu and don't have anything important on it and just want to install the new version, do I need to know the password in order to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. The new Ubuntu will erase everything and you will be prompted to set up a new user name and a new password.